# Can I do a PhD in applied mathematics where I want to apply mathematics to mental health. is

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, health, sci-hub

I want to do a PhD in applied mathematics where my focus is on mental health.

I honestly don't know how I can do that,

Comment: do you already have a research proposal, or you are looking for PhD programs that (somehow) focus on studying mental health problems with mathematical tools?

Comment: I honestly do not have a proposal yet, I am looking for Applied Mathematics PhD programs that focus on mental health

Comment: Let me reassure you: applied mathematics is *everywhere*. I mean it. Every science research lab in every domain offers PhDs for applied math students. In fact, "mental health + applied math" is incredibly vast and vague and regroups a ton of different domains, each of which has tons of opportunities for PhD. It could be image analysis for neuroscience. It could be statistics for social sciences. It could be a ton of very diverse topics. Write a list of topics that interest you, search for labs that have PhD programs in these topics, and submit your application for the job.

Comment: Then your question is what we call a shopping question, thus is off topic (therefore it was closed). I would suggest you to better shape (and narrow down) your idea and interests, I don't think you can find an advisor (let alone a PhD program) that is willing to discuss with you if your interest is the vague statement of "something related to mental health". I encourage you to search on Google some math/engineering departments that focus on research in the medical field.